# Do I need to call URLDecode in a WCF web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, urldecode

I have a WCF web service written in c#. I have a Put Method defined like this :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "MobileDevice?name={name}&make={make}&model={model}&serial={serial}&software={software}")]
MobileDeviceView RegisterMobileDevice(string name, string make, string model, string serial, string software);
```

In my implementation, do I need to call `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(name);` for each parameter?

```
public MobileDeviceView RegisterMobileDevice(string name, string make, string model, string serial, string software)
{
        string safeName = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(name);
        string safeMake = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(make);
        string safeModel = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(model);
        string safeSerial = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(serial);
        string safeSoftware = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(software);
        ...
}
```

Comment: Half your title is missing

Comment: And the answer is NO, you just could have tested that.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because I'm working with legacy code, and there are UrlDecodes everywhere. I stumbled on a case where there was a "+" character in the name parameter.

Comment: Before removing all the UrlDecodes, I was trying to get the correct (documented) information.

Comment: So what documentation did you read?

Comment: I searched on MSDN and here. Is this a duplicate question?